# Webm videos not displaying on the correct width due to javascript or css error

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have a bunch of Webm videos that when displayed I want them to cover the whole screen. The height is correct but the width is too short, no matter what margin or width values I change, I'm starting to believe its not a CSS problem. (the videos are 1920 x 1080 px). The solution is probably easy but I'm relative new to programming. Any help will be appreciated!

HTML:

```
  <style>
        
        body {
    background-image: url('videos/fondo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: black;
}

</style>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="letters">

<!--b1-->


        <video id="b1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/b1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--p1-->


        <video id="p1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/p1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--k1-->


        <video id="k1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/k1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--g1-->


        <video id="g1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/g1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--z1-->


        <video id="z1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/z1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--x1-->


        <video id="x1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/x1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
     <!--d1-->
    
     <video id="d1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/d1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
     <!--f1-->
    
     <video id="f1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/f1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--m1-->
    
     <video id="m1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/m1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--q1-->
    
     <video id="q1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/q1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--v1-->
    
     <video id="v1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/v1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--s1-->
    
     <video id="s1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/s1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--t1-->
    
     <video id="t1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/t1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--j1-->
    
     <video id="j1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/j1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--e1-->
    
     <video id="e1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/e1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>

    
    <!--i1-->
    
     <video id="i1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/i1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--y1-->
    
     <video id="y1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/y1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--a1-->
    
     <video id="a1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/a1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--u1-->
    
     <video id="u1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/u1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--w1-->
    
     <video id="w1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/W1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--h1-->
    
     <video id="h1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/h1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    
    <!--r1-->
    
     <video id="r1" preload="auto" autoplay="true">
            <source src="videos/r1.webm" type="video/webm">
            Video not supported
            
        </video>
    

        </div>
    
<script src="animations.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
  #letters{
  position: fixed; 
  min-width: 100%;  
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
                 
            }
    
#letters video {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

JS:

```
var videos = {
    'b': document.getElementById('b1'),
    'p': document.getElementById('p1'),
    'k': document.getElementById('k1'),
    'g': document.getElementById('g1'),
    'z': document.getElementById('z1'),
    'x': document.getElementById('x1'),
    'd': document.getElementById('d1'),
    'f': document.getElementById('f1'),
    'm': document.getElementById('m1'),
    'q': document.getElementById('q1'),
    'v': document.getElementById('v1'),
    's': document.getElementById('s1'),
    't': document.getElementById('t1'),
    'j': document.getElementById('j1'),
    'e': document.getElementById('e1'),
    'i': document.getElementById('i1'),
    'y': document.getElementById('y1'),
    'a': document.getElementById('a1'),
    'u': document.getElementById('u1'),
    'w': document.getElementById('w1'),
    'h': document.getElementById('h1'),
    'r': document.getElementById('r1'),
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    let video = videos[e.key];
    if (video) {
        video.play();
        video.currentTime = 0;
        $(video).hide();
        
    }   
});
```

Comment: It works fine for me, unless you are talking about zooming into video so no empty spaces visible on either sides. It fills up height or width which ever is smaller:
https://jsfiddle.net/vanowm/53rf0kws/

Comment: Yeah, but I want the 1920 x 1080px video to cover the entire screen and not leave margins on the sides. It's weird because the video is not being deisplayed on its original 16:9 ratio, but its not distorted either. Do you know how I should code it so there are no margins on the sides while still maintaining the videos original ratio? I don't mind if its cropped a little bit. Thank you!

Comment: You have told it that neither the width nor the height can be more than 100% so it cannot fill the screen (unless the aspect ratio of the video is exactly the same as the aspect ratio of the viewport). Otherwise to fill the screen some of the video has to be cropped (either top/bottom or sides). Is that what you require?

Comment: Yes, thank you! your comment helped me solve the problem.